# How to customize maven build

Tags: maven

I'm moving from Ant to Maven.  However what I want at the time is only using maven to compile my java resources, and put my java dependencies into probably `target` directory.  (It's because my company has centralized build servers, and I don't know where the local repository is.  Is using `target` dir a good idea?)

Does maven give a good way doing this, and how?

Answer (score 0):

Maven builds your code under

- `target/classes` for your production code
- `target/test-classes` for the code of your tests

If all the libraries you depend on can be resolved via Maven Central (check via the [search engine](http://search.maven.org/)), then you are lucky and can easily switch to it. If not, you might have to get an artifact repository manager such as Nexus, Artifactory, or Archiva in place, before you can actually migrate over to Maven.